# BLE receiving and transmitting at the same time

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I try to receive and transmit BLE beacons at the same time Android device (5.0, 5.1, 6.0) transmits beacons only and doesn't scan. How can I do it at the same time. Please, give me simple code example. With only receiving or only transmitting  there are not problems. I use android-beacon-library-2.11.

Comment: Please take a look at the following guidelines for posting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you mean that you want to run ble scan and advertising concurrently? That's possible but not with all devices, due to limitations in some Bluetooth chips.

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to receive and send data through BLE at the same time: you need to implement some kind of read/write operations list and execute them sequentially, one by one.